# Optimize Jquery Code for in-depth hovers

Tags: jquery, hover

I am new to writing my own Jquery and Javascript, and have created the following code which works, but is not very elegant. Basically, you hover over one ID, and a certain set of classes are animated with opacity. There are no parent/sibling relationships - they are all PNG's in different locations throughout the page - and I cannot use CSS animations for this project. Is there a better way to express this code? I can easily change the ID and class names. Any help appreciated so I can learn. Using hoverIntent plugin.

```
    $('#poe').hoverIntent(function () {
         $('.p_rb,.p_dd,.p_pc').animate({opacity: ".2"}, {duration: 175, queue: true});
         $('.p_oe,.p_rb_p_oe').animate({opacity: "1"}, {duration: 175, queue: true});
    });
    $('#ppc').hoverIntent(function () {
         $('.p_rb,.p_dd,.p_oe,.p_rb_p_oe').animate({opacity: ".2"}, {duration: 175, queue: true});
         $('.p_pc').animate({opacity: "1"}, {duration: 175, queue: true});
    });
    $('#pdd').hoverIntent(function () {
         $('.p_rb,.p_oe,.p_pc,.p_rb_p_oe').animate({opacity: ".2"}, {duration: 175, queue: true});
         $('.p_dd').animate({opacity: "1"}, {duration: 175, queue: true});
    });
    $('#prb').hoverIntent(function () {
         $('.p_oe,.p_dd,.p_pc').animate({opacity: ".2"}, {duration: 175, queue: true});
         $('.p_rb,.p_rb_p_oe').animate({opacity: "1"}, {duration: 175, queue: true});
    });
```

Comment: For improvement of working code, you might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why can't you use CSS animations?

Comment: btw have you seen GSAP.js? http://www.greensock.com/jquery/

Comment: The client wants IE 8 and 9 support, and the animation transitions will not be present if I use CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the are only two different animations, I would put it as a function:

```
function animate(first, second){
  $(first).animate({opacity: ".2"}, {duration: 175, queue: true});
  $(second).animate({opacity: "1"}, {duration: 175, queue: true});
}
```

then call it from the hover:

```
$('#prb').hoverIntent(function () { 
  animate('.p_oe,.p_dd,.p_pc', '.p_rb,.p_rb_p_oe');
})
```

Comment: Thank you. In the call, where does the "first" or "second" go?